# Complex query melting my brain! Rails and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I apologize if I'm missing something really obvious here, but hopefully you'll humour me!

I have these models

```
Employee - with id, first_name, last_name
Shift Type - with id, shift_name
Date Indices - with id, date
Locations - with id, location
Allocated shifts - with employee_id, shift_type_id, date_index_id, location_id
```

Now I can write queries that show me allocated shifts and join with locations, names etc. but what I was is to be able to produce a table that takes dates as columns and employees as rows to produce a roster like such

```
______________________________________________

|employee|date 1     |date 2     | date 3    |
|'dave'  |early shift|late shift |day off    |
|'martha'|day off    |early shift|early shift|
```

etc.

I'm sure I'm just pretty dumb, but how can I create these 'virtual' columns and link them to the employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a "pivot" or "crosstab" query. Postgres has the additional module [**tablefunc**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) for that. More info in this related answer:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

And many links to similar questions on SO from there.